# AppCleanerでMAMPがアンインストールできない

Tags: macos, mamp

MAMPを一度アンインストールしたいと思い、AppCleanerで消したいのですが、
画像通り鍵マークがついて消す事ができません。

消し方をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご回答願います。

また、オススメのアンインストール方法などございましました合わせてご回答頂けると幸いです。

お手数おかけしますが何卒宜しくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAMPでインストールしたApache、MySQLのサービスが起動したままになっていないかを確認し、事前にこれらを停止してから再度削除を試してみてください。